# buffer occupancy with awk script

Tags: awk, buffer, trace, ns2

I want to get buffer occupancy from  my trace file with `awk` script for my wsn.
and if it is possible to tell me the difference between queue length and buffer size.
also if buffer size can be calculated for nodes in NS2.

Comment: Read [ask] and then try again. As written your question is completely unclear and unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: **NS-2** analyzing scripts Besides the (wsn) python scripts from wsn-bmac////**ns2**tools https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsn-bmac/ , ... I don't see any wsn titles in the ~170 awk and perl `*scripts collection for ns2*´. Neither any "wsn → queue length, buffer size" . But please have a look for yourself : ns2 awk#perl#python__scripts-1-2017.tar.gz → → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZG5BVGpKT3RvQlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you for answering but i want to have the buffer occupancy of the sink from a trace file and traffic rate if it's possible.